# Clean install on boot disk without destroying raid array

Tags: system-installation, raid

I have a system with 5 HDD drives. Four of them are set up in RAID5 with software RAID. The 5th is the boot disk running the Ubuntu OS. I want to replace the OS on the boot disk without losing the data on the RAID disks. Since this is a software RAID, is this even possible? I am afraid of losing the data on this array since it is too large to back up to another drive.

lsblk

```
sda       8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sda1    8:1    0  95.4M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2    8:2    0 899.5G  0 part  /
└─sda3    8:3    0    32G  0 part  [SWAP]
sdb       8:16   0   7.3T  0 disk  
└─md127   9:127  0  21.9T  0 raid5 /media/storage
sdc       8:32   0   7.3T  0 disk  
└─md127   9:127  0  21.9T  0 raid5 /media/storage
sdd       8:48   0   7.3T  0 disk  
└─md127   9:127  0  21.9T  0 raid5 /media/storage
sde       8:64   0   7.3T  0 disk  
└─md127   9:127  0  21.9T  0 raid5 /media/storage
```

fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD1002FAEX-0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 10E47429-1422-497C-9147-D63DF3B2A1A8

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1          34     195346     195313  95.4M EFI System
/dev/sda2      195347 1886494175 1886298829 899.5G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda3  1886494176 1953525118   67030943    32G Linux swap


Disk /dev/sde: 7.28 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Disk model: ST8000DM004-2CX1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdc: 7.28 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Disk model: ST8000DM004-2CX1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdb: 7.28 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Disk model: ST8000DM004-2CX1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdd: 7.28 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Disk model: ST8000DM004-2CX1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/md127: 21.85 TiB, 24004285956096 bytes, 46883371008 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 1572864 bytes
```

Here is my mdadm.conf

```
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY metadata=imsm UUID=fca046fc:ae4dc84f:991ab852:a7f6e529
ARRAY /dev/md/Volume0 container=fca046fc:ae4dc84f:991ab852:a7f6e529 member=0 UUID=0807995b:62796044:632ee9d1:530bd009

# This file was auto-generated on Wed, 31 Jul 2019 00:07:02 -0600
# by mkconf $Id$
```

Comment: You've not yet mentioned which Ubuntu product/release you're wanting to install, with up to 4 installers available for current products; which have a *something else* type of option which allows you control what is installed (*where you just don't specify what you don't want to change; you can add it post-install*).  Are you hoping we guess what Ubuntu product, and release of that product (*plus what installer/ISO you'll use if a release that has multiple download options*) you're using?  Please just tell us.

Comment: "*I am afraid of losing the data on this array since it is too large to back up to another drive*" Then do **NOT** change your OS or make any other unnecessary changes until your data is properly backed up. Random folks on the internet will tell you "sure, easy, no-risk"...but they won't be around to help you when ('when', not 'if') something goes wrong. No-backup is *always* the time something goes very wrong.

Comment: I've set up a cloud backup. It has backed up all of the files, but I still don't want to lose them if possible on the array.

Comment: I have not yet decided which I will install. I currently have Ubuntu 20.04, but I am thinking of switching to Lubuntu or another lighter weight distro as this machine is now 12 years old and showing its age. I just want to know if it is possible to keep the files on the RAID array and if so, how, since the software RAID is stored in the current OS.

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS uses the `ubiquity` installer; I'd suggest using the *something else* option; Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS offers `subiquity`, and Lubuntu 20.04 LTS is already EOL (*being a flavor, it only had 3 years of supported life*) but Lubuntu uses `calamares` installer where I'd suggest using the *Manual Partitioning* option... but as @user535733 stated; backups are essential.. I'm not a newbie, but have still accidentally wiped a 2TB backup hdd in error, wiped a server disk array (13TB) etc... so it's easy to make a mistake even when you know what you're doing can be done safely...

Comment: If you are really concerned about losing data on those array drives, you can always unplug them during the OS install so it doesn't mess with them.  After it is installed, you can always run a command like `mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm.conf` and then reboot the system to bring the array back up.